# How to set default razor page route with asp.net 3.0 middleware

Tags: asp.net-core

So to setup endpoint routing in asp.net core 3.x, we do something like this
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  //...

  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
  });
}
```

How/where can we define a "default" page route other than index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to manually add route to the custom page in `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages(o => o.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/CustomPage", ""));
}
```

With this solution you need to rename or remove `Index` page to avoid `AmbiguousMatchException`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a default route.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoint =>
        {
            endpoint.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
```